# SonarQube analysis from maven and Jenkins have different results

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarQube version 6.7 for running analysis of Maven projects using the command `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` from the project directory using command prompt and get the results. The sonar configurations in `settings.xml` for maven (v3.5.3) are added respectively.

In Jenkins (version 2.161), I have installed `SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins` (v2.8.1) plugin. The SonarQube Server configuration is configured as below.

[image]

In the `Jenkins` maven project, I have configured the post steps as below.
[image]

I have checked the `Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment` in the `Build Environment` section and the Build goal is `-e clean verify sonar:sonar`.

My issue is, when the SonarQube analysis for a maven project is triggered through command prompt using the command `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar`, I am getting the results as expected. But when the `Jenkins` job is triggered with the configurations above for the same maven project, the results are different and incorrect. What am I missing?

P.S- In the `Post-build Actions`, I can see the `SonarQube analysis with maven` is deprecated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use different scanners. First you used [SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) (`mvn sonar:sonar`). Next you used Basi SonarScanner, which requires manual configuration of all options.

The best option to sole it is always use the same scanner. You have Maven project, so you can enable `Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment` in `Build Environment`, and next execute Sonar goal `$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL` in `Build`.

[image: build environment]

[image: build]

Comment: I have another problem now. I have installed `sonar-build-breaker-plugin` in the sonarqube server and also `quality gates plugin` in Jenkins. But the maven trigger of sonarqube analysis is pass where as the Jenkins trigger failed with error `Project does not pass the quality gate`. What could be missing here?